# Are the sentences "She wishes he would join them","I wish I could go with you tomorrow" and "I wish you would grow up" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, wish

I found in eslbase the following [1](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish)

> **Wish and hope**
>
> To express that you want something to happen in the future (not wanting a situation to be different, and not implying impatience or annoyance) **"hope"** is used instead of **"wish"**.
>
> - I **hope** it’s sunny tomorrow.  
>    “I **wish** it was sunny tomorrow” is not correct.
> - I **hope** she passes her exam next week.  
>   “I **wish** she were passing her exam next week” is not correct.
> - I **hope** the plane doesn’t crash tomorrow.  
>   “I **wish** the plane wouldn’t crash tomorrow” is not correct.

I found in BritishCouncil the following [2](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/wishes-hypotheses):

> We use past tense modals **would** and **could** to talk about wishes for the future:
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - I don't like my work. I wish I **could** get a better job.
> - That's a dreadful noise. I wish it **would** stop.

I found in Grammar In Review by Marcelle Gant the following sentences:

> - She **wishes** he **would** join them (She's sorry he isn't joining them).
> - I **wish** I **could** go with you tomorrow.

[image: wish]

I also heard the following sentence from a native speaker of English language:

> I **wish** you **would** grow up.

Are the sentences **"She wishes he would join them"**,**"I wish I could go with you tomorrow"** and **"I wish you would grow up"** grammatically correct? I believe that all of them are wrong because we don't use those sentences to express that we want a situation to be different. We use those sentences to express that we want something to happen in the future. So we have to express those sentences with the word **"hope"**.

> - She **hopes** he joins them.
> - I **hope** I can go with you tomorrow.
> - I **hope** you grow up.

I believe that all the above sentences are correct. Could you please tell me your opinion?

Comment: All the ones in your last paragraph are, in fact, grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But those sentences **do** express that we want the situation to be different! The first one explicitly says so.

> She wishes he would join them (She's sorry he isn't joining them).
>
> I wish I could go with you tomorrow (implies that I can't).
>
> I wish you would grow up (said to a person behaving in an immature way).

The first two would only use **I hope** if the speaker didn't know whether the hoped-for thing was possible or not. No-one would say "I hope you grow up". Every child will grow up unless something dreadful happens to them, and we wouldn't make a comment like that about the possibility of someone *not* living to grow up.

All versions are grammatically correct (well, *She hopes he will join them* would be better), but the first two mean different things with different verbs and *I hope you grow up* is not idiomatic.

Comment: So yes, all three of these sentences are grammatically (and stylistically) correct. They are entirely idiomatic.

Comment: I hope you grow up. is okay grammar-wise.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Hi! Thank you very much for your answer! I upvoted and I accepted it!